# Switch state based change transtion doesnt work tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, preact

I made a custom switch in tailwind problem is that when it witch transiton doesnt work I think its becouse of this line

> ${isSwitched ? ' right-1 ' : 'left-1'}

```
import type { StateUpdater } from "preact/hooks"

type SwitchButtonProps = {
    textLeft: String,
    textRight: String,
    isSwitched: boolean,
    setIsSwitched: StateUpdater<boolean>
}

export const SwitchButton = ({ textLeft, textRight, isSwitched, setIsSwitched }: SwitchButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <div class="mx-8 shadow rounded border h-10 mt-4 flex p-1 relative items-center bg-gray-200">
            <div class="w-full flex justify-center"
                onClick={() => setIsSwitched(false)}
            >
                <button>{textLeft}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="w-full flex justify-center"
                onClick={() => setIsSwitched(true)}>
                <button>{textRight}</button>
            </div>
            <span
                class={` bg-white shadow text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center w-1/2 rounded h-8 transition-all top-[4px]   absolute  
                ${isSwitched ? ' right-1 ' : 'left-1'}
                
                `}>
                {isSwitched ? textRight : textLeft}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you made it an island? Without doing so, there will be no interactivity to the page: https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/getting-started/adding-interactivity